# Проблема с параметром player из json полученным запросом video.search VK SDK

Tags: java, android, вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Всем привет!
Такой вопрос, делаю запрос методом `video.search` и получаю `json` из которого вывожу ссылку на `player` видео,после чего парсю ее и получаю прямые ссылки на видео.Но некоторые видео,которое не могут просмотреть неавторизованные пользователи,не открываются и спарсить их по ссылке на `player` я не могу...
Что нужно сделать,чтоб можно было парсить такие ссылки?

Вот код:

```
private void requestVideo(String q){
    VKRequest request = new VKRequest("video.search", VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.Q, q,"adult", "0",VKApiConst.COUNT, "3", VKApiConst.EXTENDED, "1", VKApiConst.VERSION, "5.40", VKApiConst.FIELDS, "title,duration,description,player", VKApiConst.FILTERS, "mp4"));
    request.useSystemLanguage = true;
    request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            super.onComplete(response);
            VKList<VKApiVideo> videos = new VKList<>(response.json, VKApiVideo.class);
            for (VKApiVideo v : videos) {
                Item item = new Item();
                item.setId(v.id);
                item.setOwner_id(v.owner_id);
                item.setDuration(v.duration);
                item.setTitle(v.title);
                item.setDescription(v.description);
                item.setPhoto_130(v.photo_130);
                item.setPhoto_320(v.photo_320);
                item.setPlayer(v.player);
                items.add(item);

                new ParseVideoLink().execute(new String[]{v.player});
            }
            adapter = new ItemsAdapter(MainActivity.this, items);
            itemsList.setAdapter(adapter);
            adjustGridView();
        }
    });
}
```

и парсер

```
class ParseVideoLink extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String title ="";
        try {
            Document doc  = Jsoup.connect(urls[0]).get();
            //Element element = doc.select("source").first();
            Log.e("TITLE", doc.toString());

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return title;

    }
}
```